# pjsip Registration using Outbound Proxy

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

Hello I am using an outbound proxy for registration while implementing it on Asterisk pjsip. When I use FQDN for outbound proxy , registration request is look like -

REGISTER : sip:outboundproxyFQDN SIP/2.0 and it is forwarded to resolved IP of outboundproxyFQDN.

Is there anyway where I can send the request like

REGISTER: sip:outboundproxyIP SIP/2.0 and should be forwarded to outboundproxyIP

I have configured outbound_proxy= outboundproxyFQDN

Comment: can you post all the relevent bits of your `pjsip.conf` file please.

Comment: [Trunk-reg]
type = registration
outbound_auth = Trunk-auth
server_uri = sip:myserver.net
client_uri = sip:1111111111@myserver.net
contact_user = 1111111111
outbound_proxy=sip:outboundproxy.com

Comment: [Trunk-reg]
type = registration
outbound_auth = Trunk-auth
server_uri = sip:myserver.net
client_uri = sip:1111111111@myserver.net
contact_user = 1111111111
outbound_proxy=sip:outboundproxy.com

When its send a Registration its something like 

Forwarded to (resolved IP of outboundproxy.com)
Regsiter Sip:outboundproxy.com
To:
From:

But My provider expecting Regsitration like 

Forwarded to (resolved IP of outboundproxy.com)
Regsiter Sip:(resolved IP of outboundproxy.com)
To:
From:

OR 

Forwarded to (resolved IP of outboundproxy.com)
Regsiter Sip:myserver.net
To:

Comment: Couuld you format them and post them as part of your question? I can't follow the lines as blocks of text. I will provide you a sample from my config as an answer presuming you didn't get it working yet. Sorry for the late reply been away.